# WCF ChannelFactory not accurately reporting Faulted state?

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

I'm using the ChannelFactory to open/manage WCF channels (vs. the client proxy). However, when an exception occurs, the factory state doesn't report that the channel is faulted...

```
        ChannelFactory<IContract> factory
                    = new ChannelFactory<IContract>("NetTcpBinding_IContract",
                                                    new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8509/WCFSvc"));

        try
        {
            IContract contrct = factory.CreateChannel();
            contrct.DoWork(); //throws a non-FaultContract<ExceptionDetail>() exception
            factory.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            CommunicationState s = factory.State; //returns CommunicationState.Opened
        }
```

Where IContract.DoWork() looks like:

```
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionDetail))]
    void DoWork();
```

I would have expected that the factory state returned CommunicationState.Faulted in the catch(...) block.

In the end, I'm looking for a way to accurately get the channel state when using a ChannelFactory vs. ClientProxy cuz I want to preserve session state if possible; and not cycle the entire session if a legit FaultContact<ExceptionDetail> comes through...

When a legit FaultContact<ExceptionDetail> is raised, the channel is still valid & I can continue to use it as expected.  BUT when a non-FaultContract<ExceptionDetail> is raised, the channel is not usable and should be cycled. However, in both cases the .State property is returning CommunicationState.Open so there isn't a nice way to tell if the channel should be cycled or not...

Once a non-FaultContract is thrown, future calls through the channel raise a "the channel is faulted" error even while the .State property stubbornly reports the channel is in an Opened state.

Thanks in advance for any input/ideas/pointers/thoughts,

T

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "non-" in non-FaultContract ?

Comment: meant that the DoWork throws an exception that is not a FaultContract<ExecptionDetails>() (e.g. throws ApplicationException)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need to check the state of the **channel**, not the factory.  You can do this by casting the channel to `ICommunicationObject`, which is implemented both in the channel and the factory.

Something like this:

```
ChannelFactory<IContract> factory
                = new ChannelFactory<IContract>("NetTcpBinding_IContract",
                                                new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8509/WCFSvc"));

IContract contrct;

try
{
    contrct = factory.CreateChannel();
    contrct.DoWork(); //throws a non-FaultContract<ExceptionDetail>() exception
    factory.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //CommunicationState s = factory.State; //returns CommunicationState.Opened
    CommunicationState s = ((ICommunicationObject)contrct).State;
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense -- was hoping it was something straight forward like that!